# Error: "Map Fragment was null"

Tags: google-maps, maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I have this problem: Error: "Map Fragment was null".
this is my code:
MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    ViewPager pager;
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter;
    SlidingTabLayout tabs;
    CharSequence Titles[]={"Mappa","Percorsi"};
    int Numboftabs =2;
    private GoogleMap map;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        // Creating The ViewPagerAdapter and Passing Fragment Manager, Titles fot the Tabs and Number Of Tabs.
        adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),Titles,Numboftabs);
        // Assigning ViewPager View and setting the adapter
        pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        pager.setAdapter(adapter);
        // Assiging the Sliding Tab Layout View
        tabs = (SlidingTabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        Integer[] iconResourceArray = {R.drawable.mapicon2, R.drawable.routeicon};
        tabs.setIconResourceArray(iconResourceArray);
        tabs.setDistributeEvenly(true); // To make the Tabs Fixed set this true, This makes the tabs Space Evenly in Available width
        // Setting Custom Color for the Scroll bar indicator of the Tab View
        tabs.setCustomTabColorizer(new SlidingTabLayout.TabColorizer() {
            @Override
            public int getIndicatorColor(int position) {
                return getResources().getColor(R.color.tabsScrollColor);
            }
        });
        // Setting the ViewPager For the SlidingTabsLayout
        tabs.setViewPager(pager);

        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map));
        if (mapFragment != null) {
            mapFragment.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
                    loadMap(map);
                }
            });
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Error - Map Fragment was null!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    protected void loadMap(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        map = googleMap;
        if (map != null) {
            // Map is ready
            Toast.makeText(this, "Map Fragment was loaded properly!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(new LatLng(43.111437, 12.391310))
                    .title("Perugia"));
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Error - Map was null!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Then I have two java files Tab1 and Tab2, Tab1:

```
public class Tab1 extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v =inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_1, container, false);
        return v;
    }
}
```

tab_1.xml and tab_2.xml, tab_1.xml:

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
```

This is activity_main.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <samples.exoguru.Parchiamo.SlidingTabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:elevation="2dp"
        android:background="@color/ColorPrimary"/>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

ViewPagerAdapter:

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    CharSequence Titles[]; // This will Store the Titles of the Tabs which are Going to be passed when ViewPagerAdapter is created
    int NumbOfTabs; // Store the number of tabs, this will also be passed when the ViewPagerAdapter is created

    // Build a Constructor and assign the passed Values to appropriate values in the class
    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm,CharSequence mTitles[], int mNumbOfTabsumb) {
        super(fm);

        this.Titles = mTitles;
        this.NumbOfTabs = mNumbOfTabsumb;
    }

    //This method return the fragment for the every position in the View Pager
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        if(position == 0) // if the position is 0 we are returning the First tab
        {
            Tab1 tab1 = new Tab1();
            return tab1;
        }
        else             // As we are having 2 tabs if the position is now 0 it must be 1 so we are returning second tab
        {
            Tab2 tab2 = new Tab2();
            return tab2;
        }
    }

    // This method return the titles for the Tabs in the Tab Strip
    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return Titles[position];
    }

    // This method return the Number of tabs for the tabs Strip
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return NumbOfTabs;
    }
}
```

---

This is the solution:

```
mSupportMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    if (mSupportMapFragment == null) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        mSupportMapFragment = SupportMapFragment.newInstance();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.map, mSupportMapFragment).commit();
    }

    if (mSupportMapFragment != null) {
        mSupportMapFragment.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onMapReady(final GoogleMap googleMap) {
                if (googleMap != null) {
```

Comment: I have a suggestion: Show us your stack trace, if there are any errors being thrown.

Comment: no there aren't any errors. I implemented SlideTabLayout with ViewPagerAdapter and I have two Tab, one of this with SupportMapFragment, but I can't to cutomize it because I have this error.

Comment: Quick advice: Download the Google Maps Android example, which is almost identical to your code.  Then take baby steps to get to where you are now.

Comment: Thanks Tim, It is just what I did but I'm stuck here!

Comment: Your code does not really match what is contained in the tutorial.  My advice is that you either post more information or just start with the working tutorial and make small changes from there.

Comment: I just posted more information

Comment: Take look at [this](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/SupportMapFragment) doc. Try to change your code to `SupportMapFragment mapFragment = ((SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.safety_map));`

Comment: canno't resolve this method

Comment: If I create a simple app with MapActivity.java and activity_main.xml all is working, so the problem is the MapFragment with sliding tab layout....please other suggestions??? Thanks